# Android: AsyncTask how to use wait/notify

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Is it possible to call wait & notify inside an AsyncTask? So far, I tried to use them but all it does to block the AsyncTask forever. How can I overcome this? My usage is: I have a camera frame generated, and I want to send it to server continously however, I want to make something better than

```
while( true){
 if (frameAvaialble){
    send(frame)
  }
}
```

Which drains useless CPU power.

Comment: Sounds like a [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem): your AsyncTask being the consumer, and some other source that generates the frames being the producer. Look into using a synchronized queue?

Comment: There are two ways of handling this cleanly. The best way would be if you have some way of using a listener to detect the frame is ready.

In lieu of that, I'd recommend that you use a timer and check periodically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `ConditionVariable`, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ConditionVariable.html

```
private ConditionVariable mCondition = new ConditionVariable(false);


while( true ){
   mCondition.block();
   send(frame)
}

//other code
frameAvaialble = true;
mCondition.open();
```